# "Token does not have the privilege for this request" when trying to create a photoscene

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

I am trying to create a photoscene. But I am getting an authentication error.  I can't tell from the examples what I am doing wrong.

I ran this curl command:

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene' -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiJZUlZNSlNFNTdFVzMiLCJleHAiOjE1MzMwNjMxNzYsInNjb3BlIjpbImRhdGE6cmVhZCJdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJIQXFEdEtPN1ZidVJnSDBuTDBNRkowQjAyRWxCRUszbCIsImdyYW50X2lkIjoiZTdhdzM5bnNvU3ZIZVZrQ2w4SzhKUWt1WDVqaWJWU0siLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dG9kZXNrLmNvbS9hdWQvand0ZXhwNjAiLCJqdGkiOiJBNlYyYUppRGpiWlU5bWVqeTJqdEpXUnh3OE9Td1JZTmpxbVBmNHlYZUhseERWVDRIVVVhOVpEMXp2VldWWHFhIn0.O-uBTW5ydubECaSecFa6lfIfU0oPAslCMcJ0r6ww4Zo' -d 'scenename=test_20180731110556' -d 'format=rcm,rcs,obj,report'  -d 'scenetype=object' -d 'gpstype=precise'  2> /tmp/test_20180731110556
```

I get this error message in STDOUT:

> Token does not have the privilege for this request.

And this in STDERR:

> - Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
>     --:--:--     0*   Trying 52.40.81.206...
> - Connected to developer.api.autodesk.com (52.40.81.206) port 443 (#0)
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: none   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1): } [data not shown]
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2): { [data not shown]
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11): { [data not shown]
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12): { [data not shown]
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14): { [data not shown]
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16): } [data not shown]
> - SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1): } [data not shown]
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20): } [data not shown]
> - SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1): { [data not shown]
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20): { [data not shown]
> - SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
> - Server certificate:
> - subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware; serialNumber=2401504; C=US; ST=California; L=San Rafael; O=Autodesk,
>     Inc.; OU=IPG - Core Services; CN=developer.api.autodesk.com
> - start date: 2018-03-09 00:00:00 GMT
> - expire date: 2019-04-20 12:00:00 GMT
> - subjectAltName: developer.api.autodesk.com matched
> - issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
> - SSL certificate verify ok.
> - POST /photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene HTTP/1.1  User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> - Host: developer.api.autodesk.com  Accept: */*  Content-Type:
> - application/json  Authorization: Bearer
> - eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiJZUlZNSlNFNTdFVzMiLCJleHAiOjE1MzMwNjMxNzYsInNjb3BlIjpbImRhdGE6cmVhZCJdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJIQXFEdEtPN1ZidVJnSDBuTDBNRkowQjAyRWxCRUszbCIsImdyYW50X2lkIjoiZTdhdzM5bnNvU3ZIZVZrQ2w4SzhKUWt1WDVqaWJWU0siLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dG9kZXNrLmNvbS9hdWQvand0ZXhwNjAiLCJqdGkiOiJBNlYyYUppRGpiWlU5bWVqeTJqdEpXUnh3OE9Td1JZTmpxbVBmNHlYZUhseERWVDRIVVVhOVpEMXp2VldWWHFhIn0.O-uBTW5ydubECaSecFa6lfIfU0oPAslCMcJ0r6ww4Zo
> - Content-Length: 88   } [data not shown]
> - upload completely sent off: 88 out of 88 bytes
> - HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
> - Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
> - Session-Id,Content-Length,Accept-Encoding,x-ads-acm-check-groups,Content-Encoding,x-ads-acm-namespace,Content-Type,If-Modified-Since,Range,Accept,x-ads-acm-groups,Content-Range,x-requested-with,Expect,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,If-None-Match,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,x-csrf-token,x-ads-test,Authorization,If-Match
> - Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,HEAD,PUT,DELETE,PATCH
> - Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  < Content-Type: text/plain < Date: Tue,
> - 31 Jul 2018 18:05:56 GMT < Content-Length: 51 < Connection: keep-alive
> - { [data not shown] 100   139  100    51  100    88     80    138
> - --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   138
> - Connection #0 to host developer.api.autodesk.com left intact

My original request to create an access token was:

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=HAqDtKO7VbuRgH0nL0MFJ0B02ElBEK3l&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2prod.sonautics.com/oauth/callback.php&scope=data:read%20data:write%20data:create%20"\n\n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by use of a three-legged token in your request.

Even if there is no explicit mention in documentation regarding this, for Reality Capture API calls you should always use the two-legged tokens.

By the way, to facilitate experiments with Reality Capture API I created a while ago a [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) collection that you can find [here](https://github.com/apprentice3d/forge-api-go-client/tree/master/assets/PostmanCollections) (and if needed it can show requests as curl calls).

That very collection also contains some undocumented calls,
described in [The Hitchhiker's Guide to ... Reality Capture API](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/hitchhikers-guide-reality-capture-api) blog post.

Comment: I am updating a web based service (formerly using ReCap) that is used non-interactively, so I need to capture a token, and then store it, reuse it, and renew it when it expires. How can I do that with two-legged tokens?

Comment: There should not be a problem with using a two-legged token, as it has 'expires_in' field specified in response body.
There are at least 2 ways of approaching your use-case: either request a new token before making a bulk of requests (create scene, upload files, process scene etc), or request a two-legged token and store it for each user (providing that you keep a database of users).
The second approach will also help you account the user usage, based on used access tokens.